# How to put a border-radius on a specific corner of a button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that looks like this
[image]

As you can see, the modal has border-radius but the buttons at the footer dont. I want to put a border-radius at the bottom left of the purple button and a border-radius at the bottom right of the gray button. Ive tried border-bottom-left-radius and border-bottom-right-radius but it didnt work. Here`s my codes

Modal:

```
<!--Notifier Modal-->
<div id="notifier-modal" class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-body">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-12">
                       <div class="confirm-purchase-label">
                           Only {{size}} out of {{totalsize}} transactions have been loaded <br>
                           <h5>The complete list of transactions will be sent to your email after the process.</h5>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>

           <div class="modal-footer g-nopadding">
               <div class="col-md-6 g-nopadding">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-purple btn-block col-md-6" ng-click="proceedAction();">PROCEED</button>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6 g-nopadding">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-gray btn-block col-md-6" data-dismiss="modal">CANCEL</button>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
#notifier-modal .btn,
{
    border: none!important;
    border-radius: 0px!important;
    font-family: 'AvenirMedium';
    height: 50px!important;
}

#notifier-modal .modal-md{
    width: 500px;
}

.modal-footer {
   padding: 15px;
   text-align: right;
   border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.modal-content{
   background:#f0f0f0;
   box-shadow:0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(101,101,101,0.50);
   border: none;
}

.btn-gray {
   color: #797979!important;
   background:#e0e0e0!important;
   font-size:14px!important;
   border: none!important;
}   

.btn-purple {
   color: #f0f0f0!important;
   background-color: #9c82cd!important;
   font-size:14px!important;
   border: none!important;
}
```

Comment: You may try to add border radius bottom-left and right in your modal footer.

Comment: Didnt work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.modal-footer{
   border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; 
   border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; 
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

overflow: hidden solves it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just apply a `border-radius` to all side of the modal that already has the top left/right border-radius, and assuming the buttons are at the bottom corners of that element, if you also add `overflow: hidden` to the modal with the `border-radius`, it will clip the corners of the buttons.

```css
body {
  background: #aaa;
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
  padding: .5em 0;
  background: #09c;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
}
button:last-child {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>button</button>
  <button>button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the modal's border-radius is a default to all bootstrap modals. I got the problem at the footer because I set the border-radius of my .btn into 0px. Now I'm looking for something that lets me set the border radius of a specific corner of my button so that I wont have to remove the border-radius: 0px

Comment: gotcha, other folks already answered how to apply a border to a specific corner, so I'm just offering an alternative. This solution should just be adding `.modal-footer { overflow: hidden; }`

Comment: Finally, `border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;` at `.modal-footer` didn't work at first but if we add `overflow: hidden;` to it the problem was solved. Thanks

Comment: @JkAlombro sweet!

Answer (score 1):

To put a border-radius at the bottom left of the purple button You can use below CSS

```
.btn-purple {
color: #f0f0f0!important;
background-color: #9c82cd!important;
font-size: 14px!important;
border: none!important;
border-radius: 0 0 0 20px; /*20px is example you can use how much radius you want*/
}
```

To put a border-radius at the bottom right of the gray button. You can use below CSS

```
.btn-gray {
color: #797979!important;
background: #e0e0e0!important;
font-size: 14px!important;
border: none!important;
border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll consider this as different approach since i've already found a better way to solve it. Will upvote later :)

Comment: Sure, in my case, I added `border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; overflow: hidden;` at `.modal-footer`. I prefer this because some of my modals have only one button so it would be imbalance to put the specific border radius to the button itself :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS to your buttons and adjust for each accordingly

```
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
border-top-left-radius:0px;
border-top-right-radius:0px;
border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed you have border radius set to zero important in css

```
#notifier-modal .btn,
{
border: none!important;
border-radius: 0px!important;
font-family: 'AvenirMedium';
height: 50px!important;
}
```

Try commenting it out and then adding in the bottom ones.

There are many resources online but the best one i have found is

[Border radius](http://border-radius.com/)

it lets you set border radius seperatly or all at once. It also give you the CSS to use.

Cheers

Comment: No idea how it would help me with my problem.

Comment: you can add the required border radius where is says 0 in the boxes around the while square. Say you want 10px radius you put in 10 and remove the ones you don't need.

Comment: Oh I get it now thanks. It's just that it still end up with border-bottom-right-radius/left-radius at the end. Already tried applying it to my code before but it didnt work

Comment: You have border radius of 0 important in your code for `#notifier-modal .btn,`. Try removing that and then adding it in.

Comment: I need the border radius 0 because the default button has border radius in all corners. I tried removing the !important though and add the codes you suggested, still didnt work. I doubt if it works on button. Ill try experimenting more on w3schools

Comment: Ok keep the border zero and then adding yours under that for bottom two corners with important tag. see if that works.

Comment: Finally, `border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;` at `.modal-footer` didn't work at first but if we add `overflow: hidden;` to it the problem was solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is simply a word-ordering one :)

Instead of `border-radius-bottom-left` and `border-radius-bottom-right`, the attributes you're looking for are `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius`:

```
.modal-footer {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: my bad, i got the order wrong while typing the question. Already edited it though thanks for pointing it out. Still not working for me though